# How to rename "lo" interface in Ubuntu Server 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-server, udev, netplan

How to rename "lo" interface in Ubuntu Server 18.04 ?

I have tried using udev rules without success, here is my code:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:00:00:00:00:00", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="772", NAME="LOCALHOST"
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) maybe? What's wrong with `lo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This most likely doesn't work because:

1. `DRIVERS=="?*"` will not match, because the loopback adapter has no DRIVER parameter, and doesn't have a parent device which would, either. (The `=="?*"` idiom requires the value to be non-empty.)
2. Interfaces cannot be renamed when they are *up* (administrative state), and the `lo` interface is brought up *very* early during the startup process, before udev runs (indeed before any services run).
3. It's just a poor idea, as some programs expect an interface named `lo` to always be present.

If you just need an unusually named interface, use `ip link add <anyname> type dummy` instead. You can have any number of `dummy` interfaces with any MAC address you want, and they can be created via systemd-networkd, NetworkManager, and probably via netplan as well.